# How to use the pose library in weight paint mode?

Tags: animation, weight-painting, pose-mode, weight-paint-mode

i can pose the model in the pose mode-> enter weight paint mode but its only from the first pose i entered with and whatever transformations i added from there. I also don't get the pose -> clear transform tab at the top just,view/weights. makes it really annoying switching around, reselecting my mesh, etc to just test how different poses affect or need to paint from the rest pose or something.

edit: it would also be nice if there were a way to just access armature setting in general in weigth paint mode for poses, viewport display settings options, etc